# reconstruction drawing sequence from video

Tags: algorithm, video, graphics, computer-vision

I have a video that record the drawing sequence with a pencil by a painter.
[image: video screen]
I want to reconstruction the sequence from the video.
And I have google some keywords like `drawing sequence reconstruction` `sketch reconstruction` and have searched like `moving object detection` but cannot found what I want to find.

`I want to know how to detect and recognize the drawing between different frames.` I have thought the `line detect` algorithm may work but fail. And pixel comparison seems to be bad idea. Because that the new drawing may overlap the old ones.

Could you give me some information that I can read or some keywords to search? Sorry about that because I am not familiar with Computer Image Processing.

Comment: I like your illustration, but it would help if you could provide screenshots of the actual video content. Separating the pencil drawing from the paper background is a simple matter of segmentation, but eliminating other things like the artist's hand and pencil will be more difficult.

Comment: It would be like that. http://imgur.com/FeN1IPy
The drawing will overlap when continuing.
This is my test video.

Comment: @Liang-YuPan  Can you provide sequence of video for better understanding. 10 frames are enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to look for SURF/ORB based image matching.

- Keep pencil image as template and perform matching on image to track pencil, which can be done easily using opencv/matlab computer vision libraries. `image matching`, `sift, surf, orb matcher`, `feature detection`
- Having tracked pencil's location you can look for location of pencil's nib with matching information `keypoint`,`inliers`,`goodmatches`
- If paper is static with respect to camera you can search for change in intensity values to left of pencil nib, like select an ROI within you perform search for change in pixels from previous image
- You have to assign specific threshold to distinguish change in intensity because of drawing to shadow `image thresholding`

Hope this answer helps